# How to check how many times value A is bigger than value B

Tags: python, pandas, list, comparison

I have a csv which I read with pandas:
data looks like this

```
home_team    away_team    home_score    away_score
Scotland     England      0             0
England      Scotland     4             2
Scotland     England      2             1
...          ...          ...           ...
```

I want to write a function that would take two parameters - two teams.
And it would output how many times game as won by team1, by team2 and how mane draw games there were

I've tried comparing the scores, but not sure how would I code when the same team might be on both home and away columns

```
def who_won(team1, team2):

    home = data['home_team']
    away = data['away_team']
    home_score = data['home_score']
    away_score = data['away_score']
    counter_won = 0
    counter_lost = 0
    counter_draw = 0
    for item in range(len(data['home_team'])):

        if home_score > away_score:
            home.append(counter_won)
            counter_won = counter_won + 1
        elif home_score < away_score:
            home.append(counter_won)
            counter_lost = counter_lost + 1
        else:
            counter_draw = counter_draw + 1
```

But I am not sure how should I proceed with comparing the games and counting how many times each time have won, lost or had a draw.

Desired output would be

```
England won 1 time versus Scotland
Scotland won 1 time versus England
Scotland and England had one draw
```

Comment: If you're using Pandas then they're dataframes, not lists.

Comment: Your function takes parameters named `home` and `away`, but if you don't really care which team is home and which is away, then these parameter names are misleading.  Perhaps it would be better to name them `team1` and `team2`.

Comment: Also, the parameter values are immediately lost, because you assign local variables with the same names.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thank you, will edit the question.

Comment: So you're counting matches regardless of `home - away`?

Comment: Yes, I do not care where match was played, I only care who won the match. Having an option to filter how many games were won home or away would be a later improvement.

Answer (score 5):

You could do some pre-processing to your data and then use `groupby` method of pandas DataFrame to get the output you want

**1) Pre-Processing**

Add two columns, one that has a tuple of (home,away) teams which I call `match` and one to show the match `result`.

```
df['match'] = list(zip(df.home_team, df.away_team))
```

To get the match result, you will need a function:

```
def match_result(row):
    if row.home_score > row.away_score:
        return row.home_team + ' won'
    elif row.home_score < row.away_score:
        return row.away_team + ' won'
    else:
        return 'draw'
```

```
df['result'] = df.apply(match_result, axis=1)
```

**2) Group by**

Then you filter the dataset to include only those matches that are between the input home and away teams. Finally, you group data by results and count the number each possible outcome:

```
df.loc[df.match.isin([(team1, team2), (team2, team1)]), 'result'].groupby(df.result).count()
```

---

**Test**

```
  home_team away_team  home_score  away_score        result  \
0  Scotland   England           0           0          draw   
1   England  Scotland           4           2   England won   
2  Scotland   England           2           1  Scotland won   

                 match  
0  (Scotland, England)  
1  (England, Scotland)  
2  (Scotland, England)
```

```
result
England won     1
Scotland won    1
draw            1
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi, in the second section, what does team1 and team2 refer? These names are not declared anywhere.

Comment: That is assuming it is in your function and so they are the two arguments: `who_won(team1, team2)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the filter by `away-home` would be easier to achieve:

```
df['won'] = np.sign(df['home_score']-df['away_score'])
df.groupby(['home_team','away_team'])['won'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
home_team  away_team  won
England    Scotland   1      1
Scotland   England    0      1
                      1      1
Name: won, dtype: int64
```

In your case, it's a little trickier:

```
# home team won/lost/tied
df['won'] = np.sign(df['home_score']-df['away_score'])

# we don't care about home/away, so we sort the pair by name
# but we need to revert the result first:
df['won'] = np.where(df['home_team'].lt(df['away_team']),
                     df['won'], -df['won'])

# sort the pair home/away
df[['home_team','away_team']] = np.sort(df[['home_team','away_team']], axis=1)

# value counts:
df.groupby(['home_team','away_team'])['won'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
home_team  away_team  won
England    Scotland   -1     1
                       0     1
                       1     1
Name: won, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution takes into account such details that:

- Both teams (*team1* and *team2*) can be either *home* or *away*, but
  you want to know how many times *team1* won / lost / tied with *team2*.
- The source DataFrame contains also matches with other teams or when
  both *home* and *away* teams are "other" (different than the 2 we are
  interested in).

To get the result, define your function as follows:

```
def who_won(team1, team2):
    df1 = df.query('home_team == @team1 and away_team == @team2')\
        .set_axis(['tm1', 'tm2', 's1', 's2'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    df2 = df.query('home_team == @team2 and away_team == @team1')\
        .set_axis(['tm2', 'tm1', 's2', 's1'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    dif = df3.s1 - df3.s2
    bins = pd.cut(dif, bins=[-100, -1, 0, 100], labels=['lost', 'draw', 'won'])
    return dif.groupby(bins).count()
```

Note a clever trick, how I "swap" home and away teams when *team2* was
*home* team (*df2*).
Then I concatenate both *df1* and *df2*, such that *team1* is always in *tm1*
column.
So now *df3.s1 - df3.s2* is the difference between goals by *team1* and goals
by *team2* (note that other solutions failed to recognize this difference).

Then, calling *cut* introduces proper categorical names (*lost* / *draw* /
*won*), providing an intuitive access to each component of the final result.

To test this function, I took a bit greater DataFrame, including also other teams:

```
  home_team away_team  home_score  away_score
0  Scotland   England           0           0
1   England  Scotland           4           2
2   England  Scotland           3           1
3  Scotland   England           2           1
4  Scotland     Wales           3           1
5     Wales  Scotland           2           1
```

Then I called `who_won('England', 'Scotland')` getting the result:

```
lost    1
draw    1
won     2
dtype: int64
```

The result is a *Series* with *CategoricalIndex* (*lost* / *draw* / *won*).

If you want to reformat this result to your desired output,
and get each "component", it is easy.
E.g. to get the number of matches when England won with Scotland,
run `res['won']`.

Comment: Hi, I get the following error `"values have {new} elements".format(old=old_len, new=new_len)
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 9 elements, new values have 4 elements`

Comment: My bad - my csv has more rows, that worked, thank you!

Comment: I have a column 'Date' which hold `2019-09-17` time format, how would I implement the ability to filter matches from and between entered values to the who_won function? Like calling `who_won(team1,team2,from_year,to_year). Then it would output the same as now but only from the selected range of dates?

Comment: Probably the function should have 2 additional parameters (e.g. *startDate* and *endDate*) and the criterion in each *df_query* should include them. Remember that column type and both these parameters should have the same type (probably *datetime*).